# Jmeter - How to compute average time taken per user thread?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using JMeter to test how quickly, on average, a user can load the home screen of our web application. To simulate home screen load, I am executing the 6 home page REST requests per each user thread in JMeter user group.

My question is, rather than gauge averages/stats per request, how can I record stats per user thread?

E.g. Right now - let's say I run test with 30 user threads. 30 users x 6 requests = 180 requests. JMeter records averages and stats on these 180 requests in the Aggregate Report listener.
I want to, instead, record stats on the thread start/end times itself. That is, for each thread, how much time passes from time first request is sent to last request is completed?

Below is picture of sample thread group I am using.

[JMeter Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qorxx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Jmeter Plugins in your Jmeter:
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/

After adding this plugin you will get n number of different listeners which will help you to achieve your task

You can view stats per thread by using "Response Times vs Threads"